# how to define values for a keymap with script

Tags: python, scripting, keymap

I'm very new to blender scripting
my question is first of all what are these called in the red area in picture?
when I hover the mouse over them it doesn't show anything so I can look it up
and how and where do I have to define these values for a keymap. is it easy to make these values?
[image]

Comment: They are propeties of operator used. Here operator is `view3d.zoom` and it has some property which is displayed in red box.

Comment: @PavanBhadaja thanks

Comment: here is more info https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html

Comment: Or crunch `bpy.ops.view3d.zoom(`<TAB> into python console.